# issue with app selector in IE 8 salesforce

Tags: css

I am facing UI issue on salesforce app navigation dropdown in IE8 standard:

we dont have any css added for home page components, Please suggest any solution.
Issue is not reproducing on any other browser

[image]

Thanks in advance

Another Issue with different application selection
[image]

Comment: Is this happened suddenly or from the beginning? Have you checked by moving to other tabs?
btw, your tag salesforce1-app doesn't related to this I guess

Comment: Have you tried to turn compatibility mode on?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it is happening some times, not for all users, I tired with turn off compatibility mode and it is working fine, but if you look for my edited post(while selecting other application with no IE setting change), both screenshots producing different issue, and second screenshot problem is occurring on selecting specific tab